# Code First trying to add Project_Id column when I have mapped ProjectId Property

Tags: c#, entity-framework, ef-code-first, entity-framework-migrations

I'm using EF Code First in VS2013 and cannot get past this issue.
I have the following classes:

Project:

```
public class Project
{
    public int Id { get; set; }

    public DateTime CreatedDate { get; set; }
    public DateTime UpdatedDate { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<Document> Documents { get; set; }
}
```

Document:

```
public class Document
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }

    public DateTime CreatedDate { get; set; }
    public DateTime UpdatedDate { get; set; }

    public int ProjectId { get; set; }
    public virtual Project Project { get; set; }
}
```

When I run `add-migration xxxx` in the console, it brings up the following migration:

```
    public override void Up()
    {
        DropForeignKey("dbo.Documents", "ProjectId", "dbo.Projects");
        AddColumn("dbo.Documents", "Project_Id", c => c.Int());
        CreateIndex("dbo.Documents", "Project_Id");
        AddForeignKey("dbo.Documents", "Project_Id", "dbo.Projects", "Id");
        AddForeignKey("dbo.Documents", "ProjectId", "dbo.Projects", "Id");
    }
```

The `ProjectId` column and ProjectId FK already exist in the database.

Why is it adding the `Project_Id` column? I do not want that column.
I have other classes/Models and they work. Why is this one trying to add the extra column?

Comment: When you dropped the Foreign key, is it directly getting updated to database?

Comment: @Nikita I did not run the migration yet, as I don't want the extra columns.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about adding this?

```
[ForeignKey("ProjectId")]
public virtual Project Project { get; set; }
```

And this?

```
[InverseProperty("Project")]
public virtual ICollection<Document> Documents { get; set; }
```

Might need to include this to use the annotation.

```
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations.Schema;
```

Comment: Generated the same Migration file.

Comment: Thanks mate. Adding the `[InverseProperty("Project")]` worked. I'm not sure why I needed it as [this](http://www.entityframeworktutorial.net/code-first/inverseproperty-dataannotations-attribute-in-code-first.aspx) claims it's needed when you have multiple relationships between the same classes. So I'm not sure where the "second" relationship is coming from, but it works now.

Answer (score 1):

You can also do this using fluent api instead of data annotations. Fluent api gives you more control over data annotation.

Create a mapping class called ProjectMap and set the relations and properties there.

```
public class ProjectMap : EntityTypeConfiguration<Project>
    {
        public ProjectMap()
        {
            this.Property(pr => pr.CreatedDate).IsRequired(); // If you wish to set a required field
            this.HasMany<Document>(pr => pr.Documents)
                .WithRequired(d => d.Project) // If Project is a required field in Document
                .HasForeignKey(d => d.ProjectId)
                .WillCascadeOnDelete(false); // To disable cascade delete
        }
    }
```

You might want to include

```
System.Data.Entity.ModelConfiguration
```

namespace in your mapping class.
Use this

```
modelBuilder.Configurations.Add(new ProjectMap());
```

to include your mapping inside the OnModelCreating method in your context class.